# webbrowser Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.fireterritories.child('tst').push({
      sender: 'test'
      }).then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
        }).catch((err) => {
      return (err);
      }) 
    })
```

This code I'm having in the provider and I'm getting compile error when building the app. Working fine in the web browser. 
Property `catch` does not exist on type `PromiseLike<void>`.

```
 resolve(true);
 }).catch((err) => {
   reject(err);
```

Comment: Hi All, 

Solved the issue by doing like below

 var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.fireterritories.child('tst').push().set({
      sender: 'test'
      }).then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
        }).catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
      }) 
    })
    return promise;  

i have resolved the issue by adding both push and set at same time!!. :)

Comment: `return this.fireterritories.child('tst').push().set({sender: 'test'});` should do the job.